# Centralize gradlew update

Tags: gradle, automation

my company provides a lot of java projects for customers (typical consulting solutions). These projects are versioned in git and built with gradle and therefore contain a gradlew as recommended by Gradle (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).

I am trying to find a solution to the task of updating the Gradle version for each of these individual projects. As you can imagine this is quite tedious if done manually.

The best solution I have come up yet is running a Jenkins job for each project that checks a web service for our current company-default Gradle version, runs

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version <VERSION>
```

and pushes the result. Is there any better or even kind-of-standard way?

Comment: Why do you want to upgrade gradle? Automatic upgrading (the way you are planning for) might break the build process.

Comment: Multiple reasons:

- First and foremost, the projects depend on our product API. The product is evolving over time and for example built with newer java versions now and then.

- Regular updates are recommended by Gradle.

- If builds get to be faster and/or more stable, I don't want to miss out on it.

- I want to prevent having many different versions of Gradle running in our systems.